# Projects that demonstrate django-webtest?

Tags: django, django-testing, webtest, django-webtest

Can anyone recommend any Django projects that demonstrate how to use the django-webtest package effectively? The documentation for django-webtest (and WebTest as well) is pretty light on real-world examples.  Thanks.